# WebSockets client does not receive data from Akka streams ActorSource

Tags: websocket, akka-stream

I am trying to implement server push using Akka and WebSockets and have written the following program:

https://github.com/vondacho/akka-websocket-server-push

I have tried to use handleMessagesWithSinkSource using an ActorSource as Source and with ignored Sink; My problem is that no message sent to my underlying Actor is pushed into the web socket output stream and the web socket client does not receive anything. What am I missing so that it works as expected; GET /send-42 should push a TextMessage with 42 into the output channel and be received by the WS client.

Kind regards

Comment: You get a new actor every time you materialize the `Source`. It gets materialized once [in the call to `run`](https://github.com/vondacho/akka-websocket-server-push/blob/64d02132db5eb9be02aa3d4f4af866cacb6b966c/src/main/scala/edu/noiasquad/akka/websocket/Server.scala#L48) and then again separately in [`handleMessagesWithSinkSource`](https://github.com/vondacho/akka-websocket-server-push/blob/64d02132db5eb9be02aa3d4f4af866cacb6b966c/src/main/scala/edu/noiasquad/akka/websocket/Server.scala#L68). In other words: the `actorRef` you end up sending to is not re-used for your WS endpoint.

Comment: I think you want to call `preMaterialize` on the actor source, then use the source you get back from that in `handleMessagesWithSinkSource`. Then, you'll only end up materializing one actor.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to create the actorRef and source by Publisher.
Base on your code, I updated some code. That will work.

```
//val actorRef: ActorRef[Protocol] = actorSource
//.to(Sink.foreach(println))
//.run()


val (actorRef, publisher) =
    Source.actorRef[Protocol](16, OverflowStrategy.fail)
        .map(msg => TextMessage.Strict(msg.toString))
        .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(false))(Keep.both).run()
```

```
path("ws-push-actor")

//complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, actorSource))

complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, Source.fromPublisher(publisher)))
```